# What is an appropriate algorithm to use for tax loss harvesting?

Tags: volatility, programming, statistics, expected-return

I've been reading into how [Betterment](https://www.betterment.com/resources/research/tax-loss-harvesting-white-paper/) and [Wealthfront](https://research.wealthfront.com/whitepapers/tax-loss-harvesting/) have architected their tax loss harvesting algorithms, but they stop short of providing any real examples.

Essentially, they both reduce to:

```
Benefit – Cost ≥ Threshold
```

They differ in how they define each term, however. *Threshold* is proprietary and the result of Monte Carlo research, so let's leave it aside for now.

*Benefit* looks like it is best measured as a percentage of the asset class in the portfolio. For example, if cost basis of the emerging markets fund makes up 10,000 of a portfolio and the loss is $400, does it make sense to say the benefit is

```
($60 ÷ $10,000) = .6%
```

Then *cost*, for example, would equal the management fee difference. Let's say .09% and .18%, plus any commissions or bid/ask spread losses expressed as a percent.

```
(.09% - .18%) - 0 - 0 = .09%
```

Making the difference

```
.6% - .09% ≥ Threshold
```

Have I thought about this correctly or am I missing IRR and time horizons?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that you may use an approach that includes IRR, but that's not a necessary component of what I would consider a good model. I have seen commercial tools that include them and those that don't. I have also seen practitioners set the variables in packages that include this approach, so that they were not a relevant component of the resulting model.

You're going to want both a view of historical results and consider Monte Carlo to get a better feeling for the probability surface of your strategy.

This section of the Wealthfront documentation might help you. They show that they have considered approaches incorporating IRR. https://research.wealthfront.com/whitepapers/tax-loss-harvesting/#15a-quantifying_the_value_of_tax_deferral_differential_IRR

I don't know who works on Wealthfront's algorithms, but I would like to. I cannot speak to the quality of their services in any way, but I can say that the research in the whitepaper above is not naive. And that is saying something special in the world of tax efficient portfolio management for retail investors.

Comment: I'd like to know as well. Perhaps they can respond here? I think Betterement uses IRR because I've asked them about their "deferral horizon" and they say it's 67 years of age or when the goal has run out. They [published their switching calculator](https://www.betterment.com/resources/investment-strategy/taxes/investment-switching-costs-calculate-your-costs-and-benefits/). So the final key to the puzzle is how they calculate expected returns but I venture it's just CAGR. Wealthfront is more of a mystery to me.

Comment: If you're somewhat new to this space then I would suggest that you look for research by Dan diBartolomeo. He has a company called Northfield, but has published plenty of non-commercial stuff as well as helpful white papers for the software. I'm going to to take a look at that switching calculator, so thanks for the pointer. The Betterment stuff looked solid from what I saw, but not as slick and clear a presentation as the Wealthfront stuff.